# What's the benefit of having a key and secret when authenticating an api over just one single secret string?

Tags: authentication, oauth

The key tells who you are..

The secret tells if it's true...

But, both of these can be achieved by having a unique secret string. Sort of a token.

What is the advantage of one approach over the other?

Answer (score 0):

The OAuth process has more to do with just using the key and secret. In short this is what happens. The key/clientId and secret cannot be used to call API

- you give a button on your page/app to authorize with the **key** and **redirect_url**
- user clicks and provides their consent
- the provider calls your redirect_url with a **code**
- the code is packed with the **secret**, **key** and **redirect_url** and sent to provider token url to get the **access_token** and **refresh_token**
- you can then use this **access_token** to call the api
- the **access_token** has an expiry, so a refresh request needs to be made again using the key, secret and **refresh_token**

I work with Pathfix and do this for a living. We essentially take your key and secret and complete the whole process and store the tokens for you. You can use our universal endpoint to make all your API calls and we keep your tokens alive and stamp you API and complete your request for you :)

Comment: I was asking about regular api call, not where you need a user to authenticate and grant access. Also this answer just tells the steps taken in oauth2 process, but never explains why. It states cannot be used.... but never answers why.

Comment: The why is in the OAuth process. Your question may have not been clear. Can you rephrase your question. As of now you are discussing key and secret and tagged it as OAuth. Might misguide someone who is trying to help

Comment: I mean either way the answer describes the benefit, it just lays out the process. Questions clearly states what is the benefit?